# Landtrendr algorithm using Sentinel 2

Tags: sentinel, landtrendr

I am interested in Landtrendr change detection algorithm. Is it possible to use Sentinel 2 using this API?

```js
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');
```